# how to store object state before and after setting attribute values

Tags: scala, getter-setter, case-class, scala-2.11

i have a class Demo i want to save object value before setting attribute value here is my code

```
case class Demo (var abc:String)

      val d =Demo("bob")
      var oldDemo=d
      d.abc="joe"

      println("old name is "+oldDemo.abc +" the new name is "+d.abc)
```

the output printed on the console is

```
old name is joe the new name is joe
```

i want to store object value before setting `d.abc="joe"` so that i can get `bob` when i do `oldDemo.abc`
please guide me where i am going wrong and what is the right way to achieve my goal .and i apologize if i am doing something stupid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `copy()` on a case class.

```
val d1 = Demo("abc")
val d2 = d1.copy()
d1.abc = "def"

// d2 : Demo = Demo(abc)
// d1 : Demo = Demo(def)
```

A more Scala idiomatic way would be to use immutable case classes:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val bob = Person("Bob", 30)
val joe = bob.copy(name="Joe")

// bob : Person = Person(Bob,30)
// joe : Person = Person(Joe,30)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. afaik, case classes are meant to be immutable.
2. case classes are cheap, so an immutable case class might meet your requirements.
3. If you change a mutable object, a reference to that object will not help you to store a previous state. For that you would need a copy of that object.

So, depending on your requirements, I'd do either copy the original object changing select attributes to qasi mutate it

```
case class Demo(abc: String)

val demo = Demo("foo")
val quasiMutatedDemo = demo.copy(abc = "bar")
```

or I would have to implement a copy in my mutable class (just because I just could never bring myself to create a mutable case class).

```
class Demo(var abc: String) {
  def copy: Demo = new Demo(this.abc)
}

val demo = new Demo("foo")
val odlDemo = demo.copy
val mutatedDemo = demo.abc = "bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is to not use mutable variables. Like

```
case class Demo(abc: String)

val d = Demo("bob")
val newDemo = d.copy(abc = "joe")

println("old name is " + d.abc + " the new name is " + newDemo.abc)
```